# How to connect google bigtable outside of google cloud platform

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a Google Bigtable cluster created. 
I'm trying to connect following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-simple-cli)
I was trying to download their cli project and build it, but when I try to execute any command it fails. Also I tried to build my simpler example of connector. Here it is:

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Admin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BigTableTestConnector {
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BigTableTestConnector.class);


public void testConnection() throws MasterNotRunningException, ZooKeeperConnectionException {

    try {
        Connection connection  = ConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        String tableName = "testTable";
        ArrayList<String> columnFamilies = new ArrayList<String>();
        columnFamilies.add("columnFamily1");
        columnFamilies.add("columnFamily2");
        columnFamilies.add("justString");
        columnFamilies.add("uhhaha");

        Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
        HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(tableName);
        for (String colFamily : columnFamilies) {
            tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(colFamily));
        }
        admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    logger.info("done");
}

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        BigTableTestConnector bttc = new BigTableTestConnector();
        bttc.testConnection();
    }
}
```

but when I run it on my local machine, I get following exception

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:90)
at com.zoomdata.thrift.provider.BigTableTestConnector.testConnection(BigTableTestConnector.java:33)
at com.zoomdata.thrift.provider.BigTableTestConnector.main(BigTableTestConnector.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server at: http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.CredentialFactory.getCredentialFromMetadataServiceAccount(CredentialFactory.java:100)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableOptionsFactory.fromConfiguration(BigtableOptionsFactory.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BigtableConnection.<init>(BigtableConnection.java:120)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ComputeEngineCredentials cannot find the metadata server. This is likely because code is not running on Google Compute Engine.
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ComputeEngineCredentials.java:63)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.CredentialFactory.getCredentialFromMetadataServiceAccount(CredentialFactory.java:98)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: metadata
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ComputeEngineCredentials.java:61)
... 18 more
```

It said:

> ComputeEngineCredentials cannot find the metadata server. This is likely because code is not running on Google Compute Engine.

So does it mean that this code can run only inside Compute Engine? 
Is there a way to connect to it from my local computer? Does anyone have any examples of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For running locally, you need to make sure that the environment variable [`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork) is set to your `key.json` you got from cloud console. This is the likely cause in your case.

Comment: Thank you. You help me. I set this variable in console via export but it was not seen from my IDE.

Comment: @Les Vogel - Google DevRel Unless I'm mistaken, there's no way to limit the scope of that `key.json` to bigtable. Is that right? (I hope you get this reply, it's not linking to you so I'm not sure SO recognizes the tag).

Comment: Not yet, very soon.  Cloud IAM should be available for Bigtable shortly.  https://cloud.google.com/iam/